# Oracle sql showing dates as blanks

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am new to oracle sql and this is the query I wrote

```
    SELECT dt,
         CASE b.colorcode
            WHEN '#fff9c4' THEN 'COVID +ve'
            WHEN '#ffcdd2' THEN 'COVID Suspect'
            ELSE 'Normal'
         END
            "Ward Type",
         b.code "Ward CD",
         b.name "Ward Name",
         b.cnt "Total Patients",
         NVL (a.cnt, 0) "Total Updates Yesterday"
    FROM (  SELECT TRUNC (wih.whi_doctor_dt) dt,
                   NVL (wat.wat_curr_ward_cd, wat.wat_ward_cd) ward,
                   COUNT (*) cnt
              FROM tmh.w_ip_healthinfo wih,
                   tmh.a_doctor_master_base doc,
                   tmh.w_admission_txn wat
             WHERE     wih.whi_doctor_id = doc.adm_doctor_id
                   AND wih.whi_ip_num = wat.wat_ip_num
                   AND TRUNC (wih.whi_doctor_dt) = TRUNC (SYSDATE - 13) --between to_date('20200831000000','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') and to_date('20200831235959','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
          GROUP BY TRUNC (wih.whi_doctor_dt),
                   NVL (wat.wat_curr_ward_cd, wat.wat_ward_cd)
          ORDER BY NVL (wat.wat_curr_ward_cd, wat.wat_ward_cd)) a
         RIGHT OUTER JOIN
         (  SELECT wardmst.wwm_ward_cd code,
                   wardmst.wwm_ward_desc name,
                   wardmst.wwm_wtype_wgrp_mapid,
                   wardmst.wwm_ward_sequence,
                   cvm1.cvm_value AS wardtype,
                   NVL (
                      (SELECT cvcolor.cvm_value
                         FROM tmh.t_objectmap ob
                              JOIN tmh.t_codevaluemaster CV
                                 ON ob.obm_containerid = CV.cvm_id
                              JOIN tmh.t_codevaluemaster cvcolor
                                 ON cvcolor.cvm_id = ob.obm_containeeid
                        WHERE     ob.obm_mappingtype = 350 --mapping of #color and ward / cabin
                              AND CV.cvm_value = wardmst.wwm_ward_cd
                              AND ob.obm_activeflag = 'Y'
                              AND ROWNUM = 1),
                      '#FFFFFF')
                      AS colorcode,
                   COUNT (*) cnt
              FROM tmh.w_bed_master_base bedmst
                   INNER JOIN tmh.w_ward_master_base wardmst
                      ON wardmst.wwm_ward_cd = bedmst.wbm_ward_cd
                   INNER JOIN tmh.t_objectmap om
                      ON om.obm_id = wardmst.wwm_wtype_wgrp_mapid
                   INNER JOIN tmh.t_codevaluemaster cvm
                      ON     cvm.cvm_id = om.obm_containerid
                         AND cvm.cvm_codetypeid = om.obm_containertype
                   INNER JOIN tmh.t_codevaluemaster cvm1
                      ON     cvm1.cvm_id = om.obm_containeeid
                         AND cvm1.cvm_codetypeid = om.obm_containeetype
                   INNER JOIN tmh.s_strmr_apprve appr
                      ON     appr.s_strmr_appid = bedmst.wbm_ward_cd
                         AND appr.s_strmr_typcd = 'WRD'
                         AND appr.s_strmr_enddt IS NULL
             WHERE     wardmst.wwm_active_flag = 'Y'
                   AND wardmst.wwm_wtype_wgrp_mapid <> 0
                   AND bedmst.wbm_bed_status = NVL ('O', bedmst.wbm_bed_status)
          /*and bedMst.WBM_BED_STATUS = NVL(:BedStatus, bedMst.WBM_BED_STATUS)
          and wardMst.WWM_WARD_CD = NVL(:WardCode, wardMst.WWM_WARD_CD)*/
          GROUP BY wardmst.wwm_ward_cd,
                   wardmst.wwm_ward_desc,
                   wardmst.wwm_wtype_wgrp_mapid,
                   wardmst.wwm_ward_sequence,
                   cvm1.cvm_value
          ORDER BY wardmst.wwm_wtype_wgrp_mapid, wardmst.wwm_ward_sequence) b
            ON b.code = a.ward
ORDER BY b.wwm_wtype_wgrp_mapid, b.wwm_ward_sequence
```

The problem is that the dates are showing as blanks in certain places which is a problem as the values in the dates are not being picked by tableau.

[image]

As you can see there are blanks where dates should be. What could be the reasons for these blanks??

The blanks cause a problem in tableau as the dates are not picked up by these blanks

Comment: Probably because `whi_doctor_dt` is null. I'm guessing if you do an `inner join` rather than `right outer join`, you won't see those records appear.

Answer (score 0):

A right outer join is just a left outer join written backwards. My advice is to avoid them and write all outer joins as `left join`.

(Also, the `inner` and `outer` keywords aren't strictly required. Some people feel they make things clearer, others see them as redundant clutter. I'm in the less-is-more camp, but it's up to you.)

```sql
select *
from   wxyz
       right join abcd on abcd.id = wxyz.id
```

can be rewritten more clearly as

```sql
select *
from   abcd
       right join wxyz on wxyz.id = abcd.id
```

Applying that to your query gives:

```sql
select a.dt
     , case b.colorcode
           when '#fff9c4' then 'COVID +ve'
           when '#ffcdd2' then 'COVID Suspect'
           else 'Normal'
        end "Ward Type"
      , b.code "Ward CD"
      , b.name "Ward Name"
      , b.cnt "Total Patients"
      , nvl(a.cnt, 0) "Total Updates Yesterday"
from    ( select wardmst.wwm_ward_cd code
               , wardmst.wwm_ward_desc name
               , wardmst.wwm_wtype_wgrp_mapid
               , wardmst.wwm_ward_sequence
               , cvm1.cvm_value as wardtype
               , nvl((select cvcolor.cvm_value
                      from   tmh.t_objectmap ob
                             join tmh.t_codevaluemaster cv on ob.obm_containerid = cv.cvm_id
                             join tmh.t_codevaluemaster cvcolor on cvcolor.cvm_id = ob.obm_containeeid
                      where  ob.obm_mappingtype = 350 --mapping of #color and ward / cabin
                      and    cv.cvm_value = wardmst.wwm_ward_cd
                      and    ob.obm_activeflag = 'Y'
                      and    rownum = 1), '#FFFFFF') as colorcode
               , count(*) cnt
          from   tmh.w_bed_master_base bedmst
                 join tmh.w_ward_master_base wardmst on wardmst.wwm_ward_cd = bedmst.wbm_ward_cd
                 join tmh.t_objectmap om on om.obm_id = wardmst.wwm_wtype_wgrp_mapid
                 join tmh.t_codevaluemaster cvm on cvm.cvm_id = om.obm_containerid and cvm.cvm_codetypeid = om.obm_containertype
                 join tmh.t_codevaluemaster cvm1 on cvm1.cvm_id = om.obm_containeeid and cvm1.cvm_codetypeid = om.obm_containeetype
                 join tmh.s_strmr_apprve appr on appr.s_strmr_appid = bedmst.wbm_ward_cd
          where  wardmst.wwm_active_flag = 'Y'
          and    wardmst.wwm_wtype_wgrp_mapid <> 0
          and    appr.s_strmr_typcd = 'WRD'
          and    appr.s_strmr_enddt is null
          and    bedmst.wbm_bed_status = nvl('O', bedmst.wbm_bed_status)
          group by
                 wardmst.wwm_ward_cd
               , wardmst.wwm_ward_desc
               , wardmst.wwm_wtype_wgrp_mapid
               , wardmst.wwm_ward_sequence
               , cvm1.cvm_value ) b
        left join
        ( select trunc(wih.whi_doctor_dt) dt
               , nvl(wat.wat_curr_ward_cd, wat.wat_ward_cd) ward
               , count(*) cnt
          from   tmh.w_ip_healthinfo wih
                 join tmh.a_doctor_master_base doc on doc.adm_doctor_id = wih.whi_doctor_id
                 join tmh.w_admission_txn wat on wat.wat_ip_num = wih.whi_ip_num
          where  trunc(wih.whi_doctor_dt) = trunc(sysdate - 13)
          group by trunc(wih.whi_doctor_dt), nvl(wat.wat_curr_ward_cd, wat.wat_ward_cd) ) a
       on a.ward = b.code
order by b.wwm_wtype_wgrp_mapid, b.wwm_ward_sequence
```

I think that makes it clearer that `b` is the driver and `a` is the outer-joined set, which explains why `a`-prefixed columns could be null. (Maybe you could also switch the `a` and `b` labels as well, so that the driving set is labelled `a`.)

By the way,

```sql
nvl('O', bedmst.wbm_bed_status)
```

should probably be

```sql
nvl(bedmst.wbm_bed_status,'O')
```

Comment: Hi William thanks for giving a detailed answer but the problem still persists. I am still getting blanks in the date field

Comment: Is `w_ip_healthinfo.whi_doctor_dt` ever null? Otherwise there must be codes in the `b` set with no corresponding ward in the `a` set. You might try running the two queries individually to check what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

In the b query you don't have dt column.
You join queries a and b with right outer join. So for those recors from b with no matched record in a - dt column is null.
Solutions depends on what you need:

1. add dt column to b query, if you have one
   or
2. change right outer join to equi join
   or both